# Hacking pointers in fortran

Tags: pointers, memory-management, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

Let's consider a complex structure in fortran

```
TYPE ComplexStrType
   ! Static as well as dynamic memory defined here.
END TYPE ComplexStrType
```

Defined a physical space (allocated on the stack memory I think) to use two variables of ComplexStrType:

```
TYPE(ComplexStrType)          :: SomeComplexStr
TYPE(ComplexStrType)          :: AnotherComplexStr
TYPE(ComplexStrType),POINTER  :: PointerComplexStr
```

Then, I use `SomeComplexStr` to define a few stuff in the stack and to allocate a big space in the dynamic memory.

Now, suppose I want to point `AnotherComplexStr` to `SomeComplexStr` and forget space I have defined in the stack memory to `AnotherComplexStr`. To do that I use a simple but useful trick which converts some variable in a `Target`:

```
FUNCTION TargComplexStr(x)

    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE(ComplexStrType),INTENT(IN),TARGET  :: x
    TYPE(ComplexStrType),POINTER            :: TargComplexStr

    TargComplexStr => x

END FUNCTION TargComplexStr
```

And then I point `PointerComplexStr` to `SomeComplexStr`:

```
PointerComplexStr => TargComplexStr(SomeComplexStr)
```

Finally, I do `AnotherComplexStr` equal to `PointerComplexStr`:

```
AnotherComplexStr = PointerComplexStr
```

After that, it's supposed `SomeComplexStr` as well `AnotherComplexStr` are pointing to the same static and dynamic memory. 
The thing is:

- How can I free the space used by `AnotherComplexStr` used when I defined it at the beggining?
- How do you recomend me nullify the pointers?
- Is that practice safe, or do I have to expect some strange memory leaks on the execution?
- If it's possible, how can I point the "*pointed variable*" to its original form? (Just in case I have to use it again as normal variable)

**NOTE**: It's useful because at the execution we can be decided if we want to use `AnotherComplexStr` as what it is, a complex and allocated structure, or we can switch it to be treated as a pointer and points it to another thing which already has the information we need. If there is another and easy way to do that, please tell me.

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do, but the function `TargComplexStr` is not useful - it either duplicates what a normal pointer assignment does, or results in an undefined pointer.  If `AnotherComplexStr` is not a pointer, then it cannot appear on the left hand side of a pointer assignment statement.

Comment: I also don't get this, if AnotherComplexStr is not a pointer then AnotherComplexStr => TargComplexStr(SomeComplexStr) is not legal. Can you show a full code that illustrates what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: A rule of thumb is that functions returning pointers are evil. It is too easy to forget to use `=>` when calling them. I second others, I don't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've forgotten to do an intermediate pointer to do my purpose. I edited the Question, and now it is legal.

Comment: @IanH When one try to pass a complex structure through a routine, one can't send it as a _Target_, then this function is useful inside the routine because one can switch the structure to be a _Target_ of some _Pointer_.

Comment: @IanBush The code I'm using is too big to show you in a simple way; now I've edited the Question and with that instructions have to be working.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just to have a variable which I can decide if I want to use it as what is, a simple variable, or to switch it to point to other data. Maybe I'm complicating myself with something that is very easy to do.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to achieve. You may not even need to resort to pointers. Are you familiar with the intrinsic subroutine `move_alloc`?

Comment: No, at the moment I'm not familiarized with `move_alloc`, but it seems to be exactly what I need. Let me do some test, and I'll tell you if it is.

Comment: Although `move_alloc` summarizes a bit what I'm trying to do, it's asking for an allocatable variable, possibly because it points to data which is together in the memory. And note that `TYPE(ComplexStrType)` can be static and allocatable at the same time, which means it is not together in the memory.

Answer (score 2):

The "trick" that you are using in `TargComplexStr` does not work the way you think - that function offers nothing useful over simple pointer assignment.

You can associate a non-TARGET actual argument with a TARGET dummy argument, as you are doing, but when the procedure with the TARGET dummy argument completes, any pointers that were associated with the dummy argument become undefined (F2008 12.5.2.4 p11).

(Pointers can only be associated with targets, therefore something that isn't a target cannot have a pointer associated with it.)

This means that the result of the function is a pointer with undefined association status.  It is not permitted to return a pointer with undefined association status from a function (F2008 12.6.2.2 p4).

The pointer assignment statement would then make `PointerComplexStr` become an undefined pointer.  `PointerComplexStr` is then referenced in the assignment to `AnotherComplexStr`.  It is not permitted to reference a pointer with undefined association status (F2008 16.5.2.8 p1).

Intrinsic assignment creates a copy of a value.  This is the case even if the object on the right is a pointer - a copy of the value of the target of that pointer is created.  Intrinsic assignment does not, at the level of the top data object being assigned[1], make one variable reference the storage of another.  As far as I can tell, the intent of your entire example code could be replaced by:

```
AnotherComplexStr = ComplexStr
```

If you are trying to do something different to that, then you need to explain what it is that you are trying to do.

[1]: If the type of an object being assigned is a derived type that has a pointer components, then the definition of the value of the object includes the pointer association status of the pointer component, but not the value of the target of the component itself (F2008 4.5.8).

Comment: I am using FORTRAN 90 and It is working. You can see yourself: Repository: https://github.com/SoilRos/ANISOFLOWPACK

Comment: In this case `TYPE(ComplexStrType)` is `Vec`. In one of the case of the program, the `SomeComplexStr` will be the `ZoneID` defined on [176:01_Type.F90][https://github.com/SoilRos/ANISOFLOWPACK/blob/master/src/01_Types.F90#L176] within derived type `PropertiesField` and the `AnotherComplexStr` will be the `ZoneID` defined on [124:01_Types.F90][https://github.com/SoilRos/ANISOFLOWPACK/blob/master/src/01_Types.F90#L124] within derived type `ConductivityField`. The function is defined on [371:01_Types.F90][https://github.com/SoilRos/ANISOFLOWPACK/blob/master/src/01_Types.F90#L371].

Comment: Finally, those variables are used as I said in [277:06_Properties.F89](https://github.com/SoilRos/ANISOFLOWPACK/blob/master/src/06_Properties.F90#L277)

Comment: I'm not an expert on FORTRAN standard, but if what you are saying it's true, why that's is it working on my code? and what consequences can I expect using that approach?

Comment: You don't have to take my word about what the standard says - you can read it yourself.  "Working" is not the same thing as "Correct".  The Fortran standard does not define what might happen for code that is non-conforming.  Anything might happen, or nothing might happen.  You might get a runtime error, or you might not.